# Show "more help" on errors in non-interactive run

Tags: pdftex, errors

When a build encounters an error, `pdflatex` defaults to asking for user input (`errorstopmode`). If STDIN doesn't give it anything (e.g. it's been closed, is at EOF, etc.) then it just exits. So far so good. And it seems that the `--interaction=$MODE` command line flag can be used to provide a default input to trigger an action ... [at least for *some* actions: `S`, `R` and `Q`](https://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/ttips.html). Cool, but I want "more help" first.

**Is there any way to make it automatically do [the `H` command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Errors_and_Warnings#Error_messages)** (and then `Q`)?

In short: "*dump all the help you can to the log file for after the fact inspection.*"

---

The closest I've come to something I'm happy with is a rather hacked up solution:

```
echo h | pdflatex $F | sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g'
```

This feels like something that is likely to break unexpectedly.

I'm not sure where it comes from, but just prefixing with the `echo h` without `sed`ing off non-printing characters seems to cause `pdflatex` to emit a clear-screen control code, or something like that, which trashes my scroll back buffer when the log gets printed later.

Comment: if you use `pdflatex --interaction=batchmode` then all help goes to the log after each message

Comment: Let's see... literally "H then Q" would be `printf 'H\nQ\n' | ...`, but your "hacked up solution" I think would work pretty well. (still, most of the time you don't need to see the extended help)

Comment: @user202729 the issue in my case is that by the time anyone knows if the extended help is needed or wanted it's too later to go back and ask for it.

Comment: Okay, it looks like that you're running not in an interactive terminal... still, it's possible to just recompile in a terminal to get the help... as long as the compilation time isn't too long.

Comment: @user202729 Yes to the "not in an interactive terminal", but your other assumption isn't valid. A better assumption is that getting an interactive terminal to compile from is **not** practical. -- The LaTeX compilation is a single intermediate step in a much larger and more complex build. Many of the dependencies are generated and only exist during the build. Extracting them and getting everything in the right places, while technically possible, would be extremely complex and error prone.